# Codeigniter modal loaded but functions are not working

Tags: codeigniter-2

I need help.
I'm trying to load a function from a model to a controller.

in my settings.php controller the function is this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Settings extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct ();
    $this->load->model('update_model');
}

function test_result(){
    $this->Update_model->test();
}
}
```

In my update_model

```
class Update_model extends CI_Model
{
public function test(){
    return 'test1';
}
}
```

The error is this

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Settings::$update_model

Filename: controllers/settings.php

Line Number: 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\activations\application\controllers\settings.php on line 14
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

update controller

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Settings extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct ();
        $this->load->model('update_model');
    }

    function test_result(){
        $this->update_model->test();
    }
}
```

update in Update_model

```
<?php
    class Update_model extends CI_Model
    {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function test(){
            return 'test1';
        }
    }
```

write small first letter when call method of model in controller.`$this->update_model->test();`